# EditText content size vs layout size

Tags: android-edittext, android

I have a singleline `EditText`, and I am interested in the size of the content vs the size of the `EditText`, to see if the content fits the size of the `EditText` or not. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here:

You can measure the text width like this: (taken from Alan Jay Weiner here:[Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds))

```
// Set the text size of the text paint object and use a static layout to render text off screen before measuring
private int getTextWidth(CharSequence source, TextPaint paint, int width, float textSize) {
    // Update the text paint object
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    // Draw using a static layout
    StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(source, paint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, true);
    layout.draw(sTextResizeCanvas);
    return layout.getWidth();
}
```

and you can measure the text as its changed with a watcher like this:

```
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //measure your stuff here
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```